# Pandas Dataframe Performance apply function with shift

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, profiling

I'm trying to optimize my code a bit. One call is pretty fast, but since it is often I got some issues.

My input data looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(30),
                  index=pd.date_range(pd.datetime(2016,1,1), periods = 30))
df.iloc[:20] = np.nan
```

Now I just want to apply a simple function. Here is the part I want to optimize:

```
s = df >= df.shift(1)
s = s.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x else 0)
```

Right now I'm getting 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 ms per loop. I guess it should be possible to do it much faster. Not sure if I should vectorize, work only with numpy or maybe use cython. Any Idea for the best approach? I struggle a bit with the shift operator.

Comment: no need for a loop or `apply`, just do: `(df >= df.shift(1)).dropna().astype(int)`

Comment: Thanks, getting with that an improvement of 2x! 1000 loops, best of 3: 776 µs per loop

Comment: in fact, remove the `dropna`. you don't need it

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the result of your comparison directly from `bool` to `int`:

```
(df >= df.shift(1)).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats my current best solution:

```
values = df.values[1:] >= df.values[:-1] 
data = np.array(values, dtype=int)
s  = pd.DataFrame(data, df.index[1:])
```

I'm getting 10000 loops, best of 3: 125 µs per loop. x10 improvement. But I think it could be done even faster.

PS: this solution isn't exactly correct since the first zero / nan is missing.
PPS: that can be corrected by  pd.DataFrame(np.append([[0]],data), df.index)

Comment: "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal" and the outputs don't match.

Comment: You are right that is an error since a np.nan is compared with a float. Numpy converts it to false. That is fine but the warning is still not nice.

Comment: Well it's a warning but the output doesn't match from this answer and the question, so it doesn't work.

Comment: You right. Now added this solution. It works and the output matches. But there is the warning - not that nice. But on the other hand, it is just a warning, it still works and is safe.

Answer (score 0):

@Paul H's answer is good, performant and what I'd generally recommend.

That said, if you want to squeeze every last bit of performance, this is a decent candidate for `numba` which you can use to compute the answer in a single pass over the data.

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def do_calc(arr):
    N = arr.shape[0]
    ans = np.empty(N, dtype=np.int_)
    ans[0] = 0
    for i in range(1, N):
        ans[i] = 1 if arr[i] > arr[i-1] else 0
    return ans

a = (df >= df.shift(1)).astype(int)
b = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(do_calc(df[0].values), df[0].index))

from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal
assert_frame_equal(a, b)
```

Here are timings

```
In [45]: %timeit b = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(do_calc(df[0].values), df[0].index))
135 µs ± 1.83 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [46]: %timeit a = (df >= df.shift(1)).astype(int)
762 µs ± 22.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: That seems to be approximately as fast as the solution using numpy arrays. Very interesting. Thanks a lot for your answer!!